# How can I insert spaces at certain locations in a string (Python 2.7)?

Tags: string, python-2.7, user-defined-functions

I've found many related questions, and a couple that have at least helped me get this far. My goal is to have a function that receives a string and an arbitrary number of integers. I want the function to return that string with spaces inserted at the points given in the arguments. I will use this function with many different strings that will have varying numbers of inserts and insert locations.

This is an example of what I'd like to produce:

Input a string like 'ATGCATGCATGCATGC' and indexes (e.g. 4, 7). The output should be 'ATGCA TGC ATGCATGC'.

This is the function that has given me the closest results so far:

```
def breakRNA(seqRNA, *breakPoint):
    n = 0
    for i in seqRNA:
        n += 1
        for i in breakPoint:
            if i == n:
                seqRNA = seqRNA[n:] + ' ' + seqRNA[:n]
    return seqRNA
```

The return string, however, is transposed out of order. Example:

```
>>> test = breakRNA('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTTGGGGGGGGCCCCCCCCCC', 5, 8, 14)
>>> test
>>> 'TTTTTGGGGGGGGCCCCCCCCCC AAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
```

I am a day-1 beginner so any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for

```
def breakRNA(seqRNA, *breakPoint):
    seqRNAList = []
    noOfBreakPoints = len(breakPoint)
    for breakPt in range(noOfBreakPoints):
        for index in breakPoint:
            seqRNAList.append(seqRNA[:index])
            seqRNA = seqRNA[index:]
        break
    return seqRNAList

test = breakRNA('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTTGGGGGGGGCCCCCCCCCC', 5, 8, 14)
print test
```

This will return you alist then you can create a string out of it using join function.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks, kvivek, this worked perfectly after adding "_".join(test). Do you have an idea why my iteration was generating the transposed string?

Answer (score 7):

String are indexed like list in Python.
For example consider the following:

```
test_string = "azertyuiop"
print test_string[0] #will return 'a'
print test_string[0:2] #will return 'az'
```

So getting back to your problem:

```
def insert_space(string, integer):
    return string[0:integer] + ' ' + string[integer:]
```

Comment: Thanks Ketouem. Where I think I was getting stuck though was with using an arbitrary number of integer arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
simbol = input('Enter a character:\n')
triangle_n = int(input('Enter triangle height:\n'))
print('')

for i in range (triangle_n ):
    for j in range(i+1):
        print(simbol [0],end=' ')
    print()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
string_name = string_name[starting index:ending index] + '   ' + string_name[starting index:ending index]
```

example:

```
product_rating = '4.56888 rating 256156 reviews'
product_rating = product_rating[0:3] + '   ' + product_rating[3:]
```

output

```
'4.5  6888 rating 256156 reviews'
```

If ending index is not mentioned its default value will be till the end of string.
Note indexing will start from 0 and 0:3 means it will take 0 to 2.